# script to create table in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, jdbc

I have this code that is about scripting to create table in sql.When I execute this code in sql server,codes work. However, when I execute this code in netbeans java with `rs=stmt.executeQuery()`,the code doesnt work. I dont know why. What can I do?

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME


DECLARE 
      @object_name SYSNAME= '[dbo].[NAMEANDNUMBER]'
    , @object_id INT = 245575913



DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

;WITH index_column AS 
(
    SELECT 
          ic.[object_id]
        , ic.index_id
        , ic.is_descending_key
        , ic.is_included_column
        , c.name
    FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
),
fk_columns AS 
(
     SELECT 
          k.constraint_object_id
        , cname = c.name
        , rcname = rc.name
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id
)
SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + 
        CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
            THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition] 
            ELSE UPPER(tp.name) + 
                CASE WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary', 'text')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'ntext')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name = 'decimal' 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                    ELSE ''
                END +
                CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
                CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END + 
                CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS CHAR(1)) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, '1') AS CHAR(1)) + ')' ELSE '' END 
        END + CHAR(13) as cr_sql
    FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
    ORDER BY c.column_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')

IF(ISNULL(@SQL,'') ='')
BEGIN
    Print @table_name + ' does not exists'
END
ELSE
Begin
PRINT @SQL

End
```

Comment: Are you using the same database user in Java as in SQL Server Management Tools?

Comment: Any error messages (especially from DB)?

Comment: In what way does it "not work?" Does it fail completely? Does it partially complete? Does it execute, but you get different results than expected? If you get any error messages, post them.

Comment: Yes, I ama using same database user. Thé error is "Thé statement did not return result set."

Comment: use `statement.execute()` instead. `executeQuery()` is only for - well - queries.

Comment: You should also use the `;` properly: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Answer (score 0):

`executeQuery` will expect a result set, but you are using print statements. Try changing `print` to `select`. This will give

```
IF (ISNULL(@SQL,'') ='')
BEGIN
    SELECT @table_name + ' does not exists'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL
END
```

also note that if `object_id` 245575913 does not exist then `@table_name + ' does not exists'` will be `null` as `@table_name` is never assigned a value.